# takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me what is the argument passed here on onclick

```py
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as widgets

b=widgets.Button(description='Click Me!')
display(b)

def onclick():
         print('fgh')

b.on_click(onclick)
```

Comment: google it... StackOverflow is not for this

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to use the argument, just give it *some* name, e.g.

```
def onclick(x):
    print('fgh')
b.on_click(onclick)
```

Either way, just [read the source](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/51322341d4f6d88449f9dbf6d538c60de6d23543/ipywidgets/widgets/widget_button.py#L72-L76) to know:

> The callback will be called with one argument, the clicked button
> widget instance.